# Reordering the variables

Tags: r

After merging two data sets, I have a data with 300 variables (which some variables end with .x, some end with .y and some without any .x and .y) . How can I bring all variables which do not end in .x and .y to the first 100 columns of the data set . Also, I want to have col 101 onwards be arranged like (day.x,day.y,city.x,city.y, number.x,number.y and etc). That is, variables with same name, say city, but with different extension are adjacent/next to each other. 
For example:

```
city.y<- c(1,2,3,5,5,7,7,NA,NA,3,4,5)
B<-c(3,4,5,6,1,2,7,6,7,NA,NA,6)
number.x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,NA,5,5,6)
day.x<-c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,NA,3,5,3)
Z<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,NA,5,5,6)
day.y<-c(4,5,6,7,8,7,8,1,2,3,5,NA)
number.y<-c(3,4,5,6,1,2,7,6,7,NA,NA,6)
school.x<-c("a","b","b","c","n","f","h","NA","F","G","z","h")
S<-c(5,2,3,4,5,6,5,NA,NA,5,6,6)
school.y<-c("a","b","b","c","m","g","h","NA","NA","G","H","T")
city.x<- c(1,2,3,7,5,8,7,5,6,7,5,1)
df<- data.frame(city.y,B,number.x,day.x,Z,day.y,number.y,school.x,S,school.y,city.x)
```

I want to reorder the variables in this format: B,S,Z,city.x,city.y,number.x,number.y,day.x,day.y and ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one column to create more general use case:

```
df$ZZZZZ = 1:6
```

Then, load the `dplyr` package (for the chaining operator `%>%` and the `select` function):

```
library(dplyr)
```

Sorting will get each sub-grouping of columns in the right relative order:

```
names(df) = sort(names(df))
```

Now use a regular expression `-matches("\\.[xy]$")` to capture all the columns without ".x" or ".y" at the end and put those columns at the beginning. Then put all the other columns after them.

```
df = df %>% select(-matches("\\.[xy]$"), everything())

df

    A  B  C ZZZZZ city.x city.y day.x day.y number.x number.y school.x school.y
1   1  3  1     1      1      1     4     3        a        5        a        1
2   2  4  2     2      3      2     5     4        b        2        b        2
...
11  4 NA  5     5      5      5     5    NA        z        6        H        5
12  5  6  6     6      3      6    NA     6        h        6        T        1
```

If you like, you can also set your own suffixes in the `merge` function (rather than the default ".x" and ".y") like this:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="col", suffixes=c("_df1", "_df2"))
```

If you do that, you'll of course also need to adjust the regular expression that reorders the columns.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
extCols <- grepl("\\.", colnames(df))
df[, c(colnames(df)[(!extCols)], 
     sort(colnames(df)[extCols]))]
```